# How to use autohotkey to run command line programs?

Tags: proxy, git, autohotkey

I'm sitting behind corporate proxy, I need to switch proxies of git frequently when doing development.

So I want to use autohotkey to create a script to toggle proxy setting of git. But I can't figure out how to do it:

```
Run %comspec% /c ""C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" "config" "--global" "http.proxy" "http://xxx:8080""
Run %comspec% /c ""C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" "config" "--global" "https.proxy" "xxx:8080""
;Run, "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" config --global http.proxy http://xxx:8080
;Run, "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" config --global https.proxy http://xxx:8080
```

Above is what I tried, but they don't work. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to shell out git commands can be a pain to debug... here's some sample code...

```
; need quotes for running inside of cmd (w/ comspec)
; super global to reference it in other functions
global gitExe := quote("C:\Program Files\git\bin\git.exe")

tmpFile := A_Temp . "\gittemp.txt"
fileDelete, %tmpFile%
RunWait, %comspec% /c %gitExe% status > %tmpFile%, %A_ScriptDir%, Hide
FileReadLine, tmpVar1, %tmpFile%, 1
FileReadLine, tmpVar2, %tmpFile%, 2

global WorkingDirectory := "C:\Something"
RunWait, %comspec% /c %gitExe% --global http.proxy http://xxx:8080, %WorkingDirectory%, Hide
```

Where....

```
Quote(text)
{
    return chr(34) . text . chr(34)
}
```

Here are a few things I do for troubleshooting...

1. Putting the git command in a variable makes it easy to change later or reference
2. I like having a `quote()` function since using `=` confuses me and I tend to use `:=` more often
3. Using `Runwait` is helpful if you have successive commands to run that shouldn't execute at the same time
4. Using `comspec /c` is helpful if you need to redirect script output via the commandline vs. using an entirely self-contained command
5. If you need to debug a more complicated script, set the full command you want to run into a variable, then ask the user if the operation succeeded, and if they select no, copy the contents to the clipboard so you can paste it onto the commandline.  That way when you get to something you can check if it worked, and when it doesn't, you open a command window, hit paste, and see why it failed.

i.e.,

```
;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; git_CommitAll()  - ; Commit everything on the current branch using the commit message
;
;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
git_CommitAll(commitMsg)
{
    tmpCmd := comspec . " /c " . quote(gitExe . " commit -a -m " . quote(commitMsg))
    RunWait, %tmpCmd%, %WorkingDirectory%, hide   ; change hard-coded folder as needed
    if debug := True ; set this true/false here to use debugging or not
    {
        msgbox,4,,Did command work right?
        IfMsgBox, no
        {
            clipboard := tmpCmd
            msgbox Command has been copied to clipboard`n`n%tmpCmd%`n`nClick OK to continue...
        }
    }

    return True
}
```